# Query results from Celery Results Backend MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, celery

What is the simplest way to query all results from a result backend in celery? I am using a MySQL datastore as my result backend.

Celery stores the results as a BLOB type, so I am unable to retrieve the results as a plain text.

If you are wondering as to why I am doing this, the use case is to query the results of all tasks executed by Celery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not stored as an arbitrary BLOB type, Celery uses SQLAlchemy for database backends and stores the results as [`PickleType`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) (see the [Celery code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/49f6b572e571bcb5b668ce3d25507668c877102f/celery/backends/database/models.py#L19)). From the documentation to the `PickleType`:

> PickleType builds upon the Binary type to apply Python’s `pickle.dumps()` to incoming objects, and `pickle.loads()` on the way out, allowing any pickleable Python object to be stored as a serialized binary field.

So, you should be able to simply use `pickle.loads()` on the selected data.